# Liking of Posts on a Django Project

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to create a forum website where people can post and these posts can get upvoted. The issue is that one user can upvote any post multiple number of times. How do I solve this so that a user can only vote once on a certain post?

I have tried creating a ManyToManyField but can't seem to work properly around it.

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    url = models.TextField()
    votes_total = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    pubdate = models.DateTimeField()
    voters = models.OneToManyField('PostVoter')
```

```py
class PostVoter(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```py
def upvote(request, product_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
        postvoters = PostVoter.objects.all()
        if postvoters.filter(user=request.user).exists():
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            product.votes_total += 1
            PostVoter.objects.create(user=request.user)
            product.save()
            return redirect('/products/' + str(product.id))
```

I want to make this work so that multiple users can like a post and one user can like multiple posts but a user can like a certain post only once.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should define your model like this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    # ...
    voters = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

and Update the view:

```
def upvote(request, product_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
        postvoters = product.voters.filter(pk=request.user.pk)  # Or `Product.objects.filter(pk=product.pk, voters=request.user)`
        if postvoters.exists():
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            product.votes_total += 1
            product.voters.add(request.user)
            product.save()
            return redirect('/products/' + str(product.id))
```

Comment: You need to run 'python manage.py makemigrations' and 'python manage.py migrate' commands in shell.